# orderBy and where clause not working together in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a `where` clause on my firestore query to filter based on an attribute `type` and then ordering them using the `orderBy` to order them by `time`.

```
 const tradesRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("cex-trades")
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .limit(16);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filter === "5m") {
      tradesRef
        .where("type", "==", "fifteenMinutes")
        .get()
        .then((collections) => {
          const tradesData = collections.docs.map((trade) => trade.data());
          const lastDoc = collections.docs[collections.docs.length - 1];
          const firstDoc = collections.docs[collections.docs.length - 16];
          setTrades(tradesData);
          setFirstTrade(firstDoc);
          setLastTrades(lastDoc);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
}, [filter]);
```

When I run my code, I am getting this error:

> FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/whaletracer-432e8/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClRwcm9qZWN0cy93aGFsZXRyYWNlci00MzJlOC9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvY2V4LXRyYWRlcy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoICgR0eXBlEAEaCAoEdGltZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI

I followed the link and created an index as followed:
[image: updated index]

After creating the index, I am still getting the same error. Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: The index in your screenshot is defined on collection `time-type`, while the code uses collection `cex-trades`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and changed it. Did not fix the issue

Comment: Please see the question has been updated

Comment: Is there some change in the query I need to make after creating the index?

Comment: Hi, Can you please delete the previous index and run the code and follow the link again to create a new index?